# Does VACUUM FULL ANALYZE a partition locks the main table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, vacuum

I'm using postgresql 9.5 and partman for partitioning tables.
there is this table that has 30 partitions and volume of one of them are too higher than others. so I need to full vacuum this partition but I don't  want to lock the main table.
is it possible?

Comment: Child tables does not affect each other but all affect main table.So your main table will be locked.I haven't used but there is and extension called pg_repack. I think you are searching for it.
http://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/